# How can I convert pug html and coffeescript in this codepen into html, css and plain js?

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

This is my code:

```js
fixedTable = (el) ->
  $body = $(el).find '.fixedTable-body'
  $sidebar = $(el).find '.fixedTable-sidebar table'
  $header = $(el).find '.fixedTable-header table'
  $($body).scroll ->
    $($sidebar).css('margin-top', -$($body).scrollTop())
    $($header).css('margin-left', -$($body).scrollLeft())

demo = new fixedTable $('#demo')
```

```css
@cellHeight: 20px;
@cellWidth: 100px;
@cellPadding: 5px;

@cellsWide: 5;
@cellsHigh: 15;

.fixedTable {
    .table {
        background-color: white;
        width: auto;
        tr { 
            td, th {
                min-width: @cellWidth;
                width: @cellWidth;
                min-height: @cellHeight;
                height: @cellHeight;
                padding: @cellPadding;
            }
        }
    };
    &-header {
        width: (@cellWidth * @cellsWide) + (@cellPadding * 2);
        height: @cellHeight + (@cellPadding * 2);
        margin-left: @cellWidth + (@cellPadding * 2);
        overflow: hidden;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    };
    &-sidebar {
        width: @cellWidth + (@cellPadding * 2);
        height: @cellHeight * @cellsHigh + (@cellPadding * 2);
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    };
    &-body {
        overflow: auto;
        width: (@cellWidth * @cellsWide) + (@cellPadding * 2);
        height: (@cellHeight * @cellsHigh) + (@cellPadding * 2);
        float: left;
    }
};
```

```html
.fixedTable#demo
  header.fixedTable-header
    table.table.table-bordered
      thead
        tr
          th A
          th B
          th C
          th D
          th E
          th F
          th G
          th H
          th I
          th J
          th K
          th L
  aside.fixedTable-sidebar
    table.table.table-bordered
      tbody
        tr
          td 14567567465447567467
        tr
          td 2
        tr
          td 3
        tr
          td 4
        tr
          td 5
        tr
          td 6
        tr
          td 7
        tr
          td 8
        tr
          td 9
        tr
          td 10
        tr
          td 11
        tr
          td 12
        tr
          td 13
        tr
          td 14
        tr
          td 15
        tr
          td 16
        tr
          td 17
        tr
          td 18
        tr
          td 19
  div.fixedTable-body
    table.table.table-bordered
      tbody
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
        tr
          td a
          td b
          td c
          td d
          td e
          td f
          td g
          td h
          td i
          td j
          td k
          td l
```

The html is something like this:

```
.fixedTable#demo
 header.fixedTable-header
 table.table.table-bordered
  thead
```

Comment: Each editor window have `dropdown` arrow with option to view compiled HTML and view compiled Javascript. Use that.

Comment: dammmn! thanks man!

Comment: :) upvote comment if it helped !